# lookup function returns - The given key does not identify an element in this collection value

Tags: terraform

I have these locals setup in my terraform.

```
locals {
  subnet_config = {
    config1 = {
      private_subnets = [
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 3, 0),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 3, 1),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 3, 2),
      ]
      public_subnets = [
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 3, 3),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 3, 4),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 3, 5),
      ]
    },
    config2 = {
      private_subnets = [
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 2, 0),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 2, 1),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 2, 2),
      ]
      public_subnets = [
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 5, 24),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 5, 25),
        cidrsubnet("${var.cidr_ip}/${var.cidr_range}", 5, 26),
      ]
    }
  }
}

locals {
  subnet_env = {
    default = local.subnet_config.config1,
    web = local.subnet_config.config2,
  }
}
```

I make reference to the locals above in my terraform vpc module.

```
module "vpc" {
...
  private_subnets     = lookup(local.subnet_env[var.business_unit], "private_subnets", local.subnet_env["default"]["private_subnets"])
  public_subnets      = lookup(local.subnet_env[var.business_unit], "public_subnets", local.subnet_env["default"]["public_subnets"])
...
```

When local.subnet_env.business_unit is set to "testthis", I expect local.subnet_env.default to be picked up but instead i get this.

```
Error: Invalid index

  on .terraform/modules/base/base/vpc.tf line 12, in module "vpc":
  12:   private_subnets     = lookup(local.subnet_env[var.business_unit], "private_subnets", local.subnet_env["default"]["private_subnets"])
    |----------------
    | local.subnet_env is object with 2 attributes
    | var.business_unit is "testthis"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.


Error: Invalid index

  on .terraform/modules/base/base/vpc.tf line 13, in module "vpc":
  13:   public_subnets      = lookup(local.subnet_env[var.business_unit], "public_subnets", local.subnet_env["default"]["public_subnets"])
    |----------------
    | local.subnet_env is object with 2 attributes
    | var.business_unit is "testthis"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

How Can i get the default value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `testthis` in `local.subnet_env`, thus you get an error. You need one more extra lookup, to use some default value in this case:

```
private_subnets     = lookup(lookup(local.subnet_env, var.business_unit, local.subnet_env["default"]) 
                             "private_subnets", 
                             local.subnet_env["default"]["private_subnets"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more complex situation like this where you have more than one level of object to traverse through, it is often easier to use [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html) to allow either level of the lookup to fail and fall back to the default:

```
 private_subnets = try(
   local.subnet_env[var.business_unit].private_subnets, 
   local.subnet_env["default"].private_subnets,
 )
```

Alternatively, if your module will include many references like this, you could write a local value which selects the appropriate `subnet_env` value in a central location:

```
locals {
  selected_subnet = try(
    local.subnet_env[var.business_unit],
    local.subnet_env["default"],
  )
}
```

Then in each situation where you need to access one of the attributes from the currently-selected subnet, you can write a simpler expression like `local.selected_subnet.private_subnets`.